# Console log how many times an object in an array appears regardless of the case of the characters within it

Tags: javascript, arrays

Trying to log how many times mustard appears regardless of what case it is written in. Any help is appreciated.

```
const shopInventory = ['milk', 'Cheddar', 'mustard', 'ketchup', 'olive oil', 'cheddar', 'milk', 'garlic', 'mayo', 'carrots', 'cheddar', 'Mustard', 'mayo', 'orange juice']

let count = 0

for (let i = 0; i < shopInventory.length; i++) {
    if ( shopInventory[i] === 'mustard') {
        count += 1
    }
}

console.log(count)
```

From looking online it has something to do with the following code?

```
function gfg_Run() { 
            res = arr.findIndex(item =>  
                el.toLowerCase() === item.toLowerCase()); 
              
            el_down.innerHTML = "The index of '" +  
                        el + "' is '" + res + "'.";
```

Comment: Try `shopInventory[i].toLowerCase() === "mustard"`

Comment: Legend! Thought it had something to do with that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seem fine but since you don't bother about the case sensitivity of the word, you have to convert the word to lower case or upper case and then compare it with the word you need in corresponding case. Here's the code:

```
const shopInventory = ['milk', 'Cheddar', 'mustard', 'ketchup', 'olive oil', 'cheddar', 'milk', 'garlic', 'mayo', 'carrots', 'cheddar', 'Mustard', 'mayo', 'orange juice']

let count = 0

for (let i = 0; i < shopInventory.length; i++) {
    if ( shopInventory[i].toLowerCase() === 'mustard') {
        count += 1
    }
}

console.log(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

Producing a single result from an array can be achieved using `Array.prototype.reduce()`. You can also compare strings case-insensitively using `String.prototype.localeCompare()`

```js
const shopInventory = ['milk', 'Cheddar', 'mustard', 'ketchup', 'olive oil', 'cheddar', 'milk', 'garlic', 'mayo', 'carrots', 'cheddar', 'Mustard', 'mayo', 'orange juice']

const t1 = performance.now()

const locale = "en"
const options = { sensitivity: "base" }
const search = "mustard"

const count = shopInventory.reduce((c, inv) =>
  c + (Math.abs(inv.localeCompare(search, locale, options)) ^ 1), 0)

const t2 = performance.now()

console.info(`Found "${search}" ${count} time(s)`)
console.log(`Operation took ${t2 - t1}ms`)
```

Because `localeCompare()` returns `0` for a match or `-1` / `1` for a non-match, you can count the zeros